# Plank/Mediable Laravel save on AWS S3 Private Bucket

Tags: laravel

I'm attempting to configure my Laravel app to store media files on an AWS S3 bucket with Plank/Mediable library. It works when the bucket is set to public, but encounters issues when set to private.

Here is mediable.php

```
    <?php

return [
    /*
     * FQCN of the model to use for media
     *
     * Should extend `Plank\Mediable\Media`
     */
    'model' => App\Models\Media::class,

        // Name to be used for mediables joining table
    'mediables_table' => 'mediables',

    // Filesystem disk to use if none is specified
    'default_disk' => config('filesystems.media'),

    /*
     * Filesystems that can be used for media storage
     *
     * Uploader will throw an exception if a disk not in this list is selected
     */
    'allowed_disks' => [
        'public',
        'local',
        'do',
        's3'
    ],

    'directory' => 'media',

    // The maximum file size in bytes for a single uploaded file
    'max_size' => 1024 * 1024 * 500,

    /*
     * What to do if a duplicate file is uploaded.
     *
     * Options include:
     *
     * * `'increment'`: the new file's name is given an incrementing suffix
     * * `'replace'` : the old file and media model is deleted
     * * `'error'`: an Exception is thrown
     */
    'on_duplicate' => Plank\Mediable\MediaUploader::ON_DUPLICATE_INCREMENT,

    // Reject files unless both their mime and extension are recognized and both match a single aggregate type
    'strict_type_checking' => false,

    /*
     * Reject files whose mime type or extension is not recognized
     * if true, files will be given a type of `'other'`
     */
    'allow_unrecognized_types' => false,

    // Only allow files with specific MIME type(s) to be uploaded
    'allowed_mime_types' => [],

    // Only allow files with specific file extension(s) to be uploaded
    'allowed_extensions' => [],

    // Only allow files matching specific aggregate type(s) to be uploaded
    'allowed_aggregate_types' => [],

    /*
     * List of aggregate types recognized by the application
     *
     * Each type should list the MIME types and extensions
     * that should be recognized for the type
     */
    'aggregate_types' => [
        Plank\Mediable\Media::TYPE_IMAGE => [
            'mime_types' => [
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/gif',
            ],
            'extensions' => [
                'jpg',
                'jpeg',
                'png',
                'gif',
            ]
        ],
        Plank\Mediable\Media::TYPE_IMAGE_VECTOR => [
            'mime_types' => [
                'image/svg+xml',
            ],
            'extensions' => [
                'svg',
            ]
        ],
        Plank\Mediable\Media::TYPE_PDF => [
            'mime_types' => [
                'application/pdf',
            ],
            'extensions' => [
                'pdf',
            ]
        ],
        Plank\Mediable\Media::TYPE_AUDIO => [
            'mime_types' => [
                'audio/aac',
                'audio/ogg',
                'audio/mpeg',
                'audio/mp3',
                'audio/mpeg',
                'audio/wav'
            ],
            'extensions' => [
                'aac',
                'ogg',
                'oga',
                'mp3',
                'wav',
            ]
        ],
        Plank\Mediable\Media::TYPE_VIDEO => [
            'mime_types' => [
                'video/mp4',
                'video/mpeg',
                'video/ogg',
                'video/webm'
            ],
            'extensions' => [
                'mp4',
                'm4v',
                'mov',
                'ogv',
                'webm'
            ]
        ],
        Plank\Mediable\Media::TYPE_ARCHIVE => [
            'mime_types' => [
                'application/zip',
                'application/x-compressed-zip',
                'multipart/x-zip',
            ],
            'extensions' => [
                'zip',
            ]
        ],
        Plank\Mediable\Media::TYPE_DOCUMENT => [
            'mime_types' => [
                'text/plain',
                'application/plain',
                'text/xml',
                'text/json',
                'application/json',
                'application/msword',
                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
            ],
            'extensions' => [
                'doc',
                'docx',
                'txt',
                'text',
                'xml',
                'json',
            ]
        ],
        Plank\Mediable\Media::TYPE_SPREADSHEET => [
            'mime_types' => [
                'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
            ],
            'extensions' => [
                'xls',
                'xlsx',
            ]
        ],
        Plank\Mediable\Media::TYPE_PRESENTATION => [
            'mime_types' => [
                    'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
                    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
                    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow'
                ],
            'extensions' => [
                    'ppt',
                    'pptx',
                    'ppsx',
                ]
        ],
    ],

    /*
     * List of adapters to use for various source inputs
     *
     * Adapters can map either to a class or a pattern (regex)
     */
    'source_adapters' => [
        'class' => [
            Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::class => Plank\Mediable\SourceAdapters\UploadedFileAdapter::class,
            Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File::class => Plank\Mediable\SourceAdapters\FileAdapter::class,
            Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface::class => Plank\Mediable\SourceAdapters\StreamAdapter::class,
        ],
        'pattern' => [
            '^https?://' => Plank\Mediable\SourceAdapters\RemoteUrlAdapter::class,
            '^/' => Plank\Mediable\SourceAdapters\LocalPathAdapter::class,
            '^[a-zA-Z]:\\\\' => Plank\Mediable\SourceAdapters\LocalPathAdapter::class
        ],
    ],

    // List of URL Generators to use for handling various filesystem drivers
    'url_generators' => [
        'local' => Plank\Mediable\UrlGenerators\LocalUrlGenerator::class,
        's3' => Plank\Mediable\UrlGenerators\S3UrlGenerator::class,
    ],

    /*
     * Should mediable instances automatically reload their media relationships after modification are made to a tag.
     *
     * If true, will automatically reload media the next time `getMedia()`, `getMediaMatchAll()` or `getAllMediaByTag()` are called.
     */
    'rehydrate_media' => true,

    // Detach associated media when mediable model is soft deleted.
    'detach_on_soft_delete' => false,

    'demo_image_provider' => env('DEMO_IMAGE_PROVIDER', 'local')
];
```

and filesystem.php

```
    <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' =>  env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    'media' => env('FILESYSTEM_MEDIA', 's3'),
    'media-prefix' => env('FILESYSTEM_MEDIA_PREFIX'),

    'tickets' => env('FILESYSTEM_TICKETS', 'local'),
    'tickets-prefix' => env('FILESYSTEM_TICKETS_PREFIX'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'visibility' => 'private'
        ],

        'minio' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => true,
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET')
        ],

        'do' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('DO_SPACES_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('DO_SPACES_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('DO_SPACES_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('DO_SPACES_BUCKET'),
            'endpoint' => 'https://' . env('DO_SPACES_REGION') . '.digitaloceanspaces.com',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];
```

When set to private, I've attempted a simple example like this

$disk = Storage::disk('s3');
$filePath = 'media/file-test.txt';
$fileContents = 'Hello, this a test!';
$disk->put($filePath, $fileContents);
$fileContent = $disk->get($filePath);

It works fine independently, but when I integrate the library, it doesn't.